# Is this undefined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, strict-aliasing

This example is copied from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).

```cpp
struct Y { int z; };
alignas(Y) std::byte s[sizeof(Y)];
Y* q = new(&s) Y{2};
const int f = reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&s)->z; // Class member access is undefined
                                           // behavior: reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&s)
                                           // has value "pointer to s" and does
                                           // not point to a Y object
const int g = q->z; // OK
const int h = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&s))->z; // OK
```

I wonder if adding operations like `s[0] = std::byte{0}` after statements above is undefined behavior? It seems that it doesn't disobey *strict aliasing rule*, for `std::byte` can be an "AliasedType" for any type according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), which means it's legal to view any object as array of bytes.

Notice that I add c++20 label because they may only be well-defined after C++20.

Comment: It is legal to view anything as an array of bytes but It is not legal to view an array of bytes as anything else.

Comment: "std::byte is a similar type to any type" AFAICT cppreference does not make any such claim. It is simply not true.

Comment: @n.m. I've changed my wording, sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, this behaviour is well-defined precisely because `std::byte` is an "AliasedType".

Comment: @JMuzhen in the firtst reinterpret_cast std::byte is DynamicType and not AliasedType

Comment: I would argue that the statement, "does not point to a Y object" is wrong, because it *does* point to a Y object ... one created (and **constructed**) by the placement new.

Comment: It 8s not about what *can* be AliasedType (anything can be), it is about what *is* AliasedType in a specific expression.

Comment: @AdrianMole the statement is correct. The pointer does not point to a Y object. A true statement can be made, e.g. "there is a Y object at the same address as the byte array object pointed to by the pointer". There is a subtle but important difference between the two. It is precisely because of this difference `std::launder` is needed.

Comment: _I wonder if adding operations like `s[0] = std::byte{0}` after statements above is undefined behavior?_ You mean after `new(&s) Y{2}`? Yes, it is undefined behavior because it would be an access to an out-of-lifetime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated my answer thanks to @LanguageLawyer's correction.

---

> I wonder if adding operations like s[0] = std::byte{0} after statements above is undefined behavior?

I believe this is an undefined behavior, but the reason has nothing to do with strict aliasing rules. Strict aliasing rules state that if the program accesses an object of type `D` through a glvalue of type `T` but `D` and `T` are not "similar" and `T` is not one of those special character types, the program has undefined behaviors. In your case, you're accessing a `std::byte` object through a glvalue of type `std::byte`, which is perfectly fine under strict aliasing rules.

The real problem here is that `s` also provides storage for another `Y` object. Once `s` provides storage for the `Y` object (after the new expression), the lifetime of the array elements is terminated because their storage is reused:

> [basic.life]/1.2:
>
> The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>
> - if T is a non-class type, the object is destroyed, or
> - if T is a class type, the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o ([intro.object]).

So if you access `s[0]` after the new expression, you are accessing an out-of-lifetime object, which is an undefined behavior.

Comment: _Note that the `std::byte[]` is still alive because providing storage does not terminate the lifetime of the array object_ But does terminate the lifetime of its elements

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Can you give a reference to the corresponding standard text? I didn't expect an array to be alive while its elements are dead.

Comment: _Can you give a reference to the corresponding standard text?_ It is in your answer: «the storage which the object occupies ... is reused»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh I understand. So the idea is that the array also provides storage for its elements, and the elements are terminated once the storage is reused.

Comment: _So the idea is that the array also provides storage for its elements_ Ehm, no, [«provides storage»](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#def:provides_storage) does not apply here

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OK. So the elements are terminated simply because their associated storage is reused by the new object.

Comment: So if I hope to modify some bytes in the object `*q`, I need to code like `std::byte* viewAsBytes = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(q); viewAsBytes[1] = std::byte{0x10};`, but cannot use the original variable `s`, right?

Comment: @o_oTurtle Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that it doesn't disobey strict aliasing rule, for std::byte can be an "AliasedType" for any type

While `std::byte` can be `AliasedType` for anything, it isn't in this fragment. `Y` is the `AliasedType`, for we are trying to access an object<sup>1</sup> trough a glvalue of type `Y`<sup>2</sup>.

> it's legal to view any object as array of bytes

It is indeed legal to view any object as an array of bytes. This `reinterpret_cast`, however, is trying to do exactly the opposite: view an array of bytes as some other type. This isn't and never was legal.

--
<sup>1</sup>In this case, `s`.
<sup>2</sup>In this case, `*reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&s)`.

Comment: In the days before the Standard, such constructs were legal and 100% reliable on many compilers, if the bit patterns of the underlying types were compatible, and for many such constructs there was never any reason why quality compilers shouldn't support them.  Note further that the C++ Standard does *not* define any category of conformance for C++ *programs* but only *implementations*.  Unfortunately, the Stadnard can't add official support for such constructs because the most logical syntax would be the same syntax as was used before the Standard, and which should always have been supported.